# How to specify JMX port number dynamically

Tags: java, rmi, jmx

I am trying to set the port number at which the JMX server starts dynamically through the program. Usually it is done using -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1234 (static port), which works fine. Any thoughts on how can it be done dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

`System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.port", "1234");`

Comment: This does not work - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276881/how-to-set-jmx-remote-port-system-environment-parameters-through-java-code-for-r